# Pro Tools / show all written automation

Tags: pro-tools, automation

sorry if this question is too off-topic and far from sound design.
I'm wondering whether there's any way how to easily show all automation lanes that have any data written inside. I hope you know what I mean. I sometimes find myself struggling with English.
I did, of course, some research first before asking this question but no luck so far.
It seems that I have to open lanes one by one like I'm used to do but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: what do you exactly mean with 'all automation lanes that have any data written"? for a particular channel or for all channels?

Comment: Sorry Arnaud, I meant for a particular track and a particular plugin etc. For example, when I write automation for a surround panner I'd like to reveal all data that have just been written. Does it make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no way to do what you're asking. I'm fairly confident that opening individual automation lanes one by one is the only way.

Comment: I think so too. To add on, your best bet is to probably do an 'option + A" then show all automation and then quickly dismissing all those lanes with no breakpoints. Maybe useful to also know that 'CTRL + Command + Left/Right' arrow keys will let you cycle through each lane of automation.

Answer (score 2):

"Option -" (minus sign) Shows all volume automation. Cntrl+Command Left and Right Arrow keys goes through all the automation paramters on a selected track. And Cntrl Option Cmnd left and right on arrow keys goes through all the automation paramters on ALL tracks.

Comment: The last response about ctrl-option-command-click is not what the OP was asking about. That is the function to enable automation for the entire plugin. It'll open a popup menu. I'm also looking for a key command to "show all used automation" for either an individual track, or the entire project. It looks like it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+click on the little arrow in any track. Alt-clicking will show/hide all automation lanes.

Comment: I seems the question was whether there is a way to quickly show ONLY the lanes that have points in them, while keeping the empty ones hidden. What you're suggesting simply shows all automation lanes, regardless of content.

Answer (score 0):

After your response it's way easier to answer your question. Yes you can.
In Protools plugins just hold the ctrl-option-command keys together and click on the plugin button you want to automate (whatever it is from which you want to see the automation lane).
It works in eq plugins and also on channelstrips. Don't know about surround, just try it out.
Then you can ctrl-command and click on the same button. Easy does it.

[SOS link](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/sep05/articles/keypoints.htm)